# HP QC: How do I generate a report for resource wise test runs for a particular folder?

Tags: manual-testing, quality-center, regression-testing, hp-alm

We have several folders in Test Lab having test cases. The work is divided between 4 resources for execution. How can I generate a report at the end of the day which shows how many test cases have been run by which resource?

For example, let's say we have 2 folders Regression and Progression. And, 2 resources, x and y. The report should give me something like this:

Regression: x=(no. of test cases ran by x on that day) and y=(no. of test cases ran by y on that day)
Progression: x=(no. of test cases ran by x on that day) and y=(no. of test cases ran by y on that day)

Comment: I found this step-by-step guide: http://qafriend.com/alm-quality-center/reporting-graphs-in-alm-quality-center
See if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

On HP ALM 11
Go to Test Lab, select the folder that you want to generate graph for.
At your right you will see a pane with Live Analysis hyperlink. Click on that which will open up a small window with various filter options.

Select on X axis the field that has your tester details e.g. responsible tester or test designer, etc.

On Y axis choose your required field like Status for test runs/cases

and then click next.

Thats it your graph will be ready.

Alternatively you can also use Analysis on the menu bar or can also use Management Module.

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Graph Wizard you can use the TestSet Name and the Test Subject (Test Plan path) but the Test Lab path is not available.

If you are confortable with SQL and Excel VBA you can create an Excel Report using queries to extract exactly the data you want and execute some script to format and add graphs to the generated Excel file.
The same think may be possible using Business View, to create a Business View you need access to the QC/ALM backend.